# Issues creating a linked list using a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, nodes

Below is my code to try and create a linked list of 10 integers. Then to traverse through the list, to half the even numbers and double the odd ones.
I've looked around online to see how to create the list with the use of a function. I interpreted that to write the function in the code shown below: "void createList()". The code compiles fine but when I run it I only get the following output:

Original list:

Updated list:

Does anyone know where the issue is coming from? Is it from the createList function or the display function? Or even elsewhere?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;  
};

void freeList();
void update();
void createList();
void display();
struct node* root = NULL;

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    createList((rand() % 10) + 1);
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();
    createList();

    printf("Original list:");
    display();


    update();


    printf("\nUpdated list:");
    display();

    freeList();

    return 0;
}


void createList()
{
    struct node* tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->data = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* p;
        p = root;

        while (p->next != NULL)
        {
            p = p->next;
        } 
        p->next = tmp;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node* tmp;
    tmp = root;
    if (tmp = NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(tmp != NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%d", tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void freeList()
{

    struct node* tmp;
    tmp = root;
    if (tmp = NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            free(tmp);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        } 
        printf("\n");

    }
}

void update()
{
    struct node* tmp;
    tmp = root;
    if (tmp = NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty.\n");
    }  
    else
    { 
        while (tmp != NULL)
        { 
            if (root->data % 2 == 0)
            {
                root->data = root->data / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                root->data = root->data * 2;
            }
            printf("\t%d", root->data);
            root = root->next;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (tmp = NULL)`: `= --> ==`.

Comment: `if (tmp = NULL)` The compiler should be screaming about that. If you're compiling with gcc or clang, be sure to use the `-Wall` option, and make sure that you understand and fix every warning.

Comment: @user3386109 only thing compiler gives a warning about is "conversion from time_t to unsigned int, possible loss of data."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a number of

```
if (tmp = NULL)
```

which should be

```
if (tmp == NULL)
```

or otherwise you always reset tmp to NULL and the "if" never enters.

Second, in the update() you deal with "root" instead of "tmp", correct is

```
    while (tmp != NULL)
    { 
        if (tmp->data % 2 == 0)
        {
            tmp->data = tmp->data / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->data = tmp->data * 2;
        }
        printf("\t%d", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
```

so actually you have been pretty close already. ps.: first call to

```
createList((rand() % 10) + 1)
```

needs no arguments

Comment: Thanks @Pedro. It now prints the list but gives a new error in the freeList() function. It says: "Exception thrown: read access violation. it was 0xDDDDDDD4." On the line free(tmp).

Comment: Any ideas why? @Pedro

Comment: oops, one thing slipped through: yes, in free you have             "free(tmp);" and then "tmp = tmp->next;" which of course doesnt work, you cannot access tmp->next after you freed tmp. What you have to do is to keep a copy of the next elemnt before you free the current one, something like: "struct node* nextTmp = tmp->next; free(tmp); tmp = nextTmp;"

Answer (score 1):

In `display` and elsewhere you have

```
if (tmp = NULL)
```

This is clearly incorrect because it assigns `NULL` to `tmp` making it look like a zero length list.

When I compiled your program (using clang), the output I got was this:

```
jeremyp@Magenta:jeremyp% cc foo.c
foo.c:75:13: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without
      parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if (tmp = NULL)
        ~~~~^~~~~~
foo.c:75:13: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this
      warning
    if (tmp = NULL)
            ^
        (         )
foo.c:75:13: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if (tmp = NULL)
            ^
            ==
foo.c:96:13: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without
      parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if (tmp = NULL)
        ~~~~^~~~~~
foo.c:96:13: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this
      warning
    if (tmp = NULL)
            ^
        (         )
foo.c:96:13: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if (tmp = NULL)
            ^
            ==
foo.c:116:13: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without
      parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if (tmp = NULL)
        ~~~~^~~~~~
foo.c:116:13: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this
      warning
    if (tmp = NULL)
            ^
        (         )
foo.c:116:13: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if (tmp = NULL)
            ^
            ==
3 warnings generated.
```

You are probably using either clang or gcc both of which will display warnings similar to the above. My advice is *do not ignore the warnings, even if an executable is emitted*.

If your compiler does not emit warnings on the code in your question (even with the `-Wall` switch), throw it away and get a better one. I have many years of experience finding out that ignoring warnings causes a lot of extra work and debugging frustration.

If you are using Visual Studio (unlucky!), it also has a warning for this. Apparently [it is a level 4 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4706?view=vs-2017) so you need the switch `/W4`. I don't have access to Visual Studio, so I can't verify it, unfortunately.

Comment: Hey @JeremyP, thanks for your help. I'm using visual studio as it's the one that has been supplied to me from my University.

Comment: @OllieParsons Try adding the [/W4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4706?view=vs-2017) switch to the compile command